# How to loop and calculate to zero php

Tags: php

I have a array with values. I want to reduce the amount if someone buys an item.
For example if someone buys 45 items I want to loop the array values and calculate with the purchaded items until whats left.

What I tried.

```
 <?php
  $purchased = 45;
  $stock = array(40, 50, 60);

   for( $i = 0; $i < count($stock); $i++ ){
     $left = $stock[$i]-$purchased;
     echo $left . "\n";
   }

// result: -5, 5, 15
// needs to be: 0, 45, 60
?>
```

As suggested to show the code. its dutch column names. It has nothing to do with purchasing. I did it in the example to clarify.

```
$select = $db->prepare("SELECT c.id, d.id AS grondstofid, d.naam, 
(a.aantal/b.volume)*c.aantal AS afschrijving 
FROM ".DB04.".verkooporderregelstemp AS a 
INNER JOIN ".DB02.".recepten AS b ON a.receptid=b.id 
INNER JOIN ".DB02.".receptgrondstoffen AS c ON a.receptid=c.receptid
INNER JOIN ".DB02.".grondstoffen AS d ON c.grondstofid=d.id 
WHERE a.guid=:guid AND a.productie='1' AND c.grondstofid='1' GROUP BY c.id");
    $select->bindValue(":guid", $guid);
    $select->execute();
    $result = $select->fetchAll();
    foreach ($result as $data) {
      $grondstofid = $data['grondstofid'];
      $afschrijving = $data['afschrijving']; // this is the total reduction 

      $select1 = $db->prepare("SELECT id, voorraad FROM ".DB02.".grondstofbatch WHERE grondstofid=:grondstofid AND FROM_UNIXTIME(thtdatum)>CURRENT_TIMESTAMP GROUP BY id ORDER BY thtdatum ASC");
      $subselect->bindValue(":grondstofid", $grondstofid);
      $subselect->execute();
      $subresult = $subselect->fetchAll();
      foreach ($subresult as $subdata) {
       $subdata['voorraad']; // 3 rows
       
       //batch 1 - AMOUNT 40
       //batch 2 - AMOUNT 50
       //batch 3 - AMOUNT 60

       // some loop for $subdata['voorraad']-$afschrijving
       // update SQL
       // if its hits zero get remaining $afschrijving goto next row
      }
    }
```

Comment: how come 45 and 60?

Comment: I thought you were trying to do this using a database [earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73969518/update-stock-fifo-mysql)! What changed

Comment: So you have to do some testing inside the loop, not just blindly subtract the purchased amount. There is no magic bullet, it has to be coded

Comment: @riggsFolly not possible with mysql or not possible with PDO mysql. So trying it in php

Comment: ___You really must read the comments properly!!___ @shadow said "its not possible in ONE SQL COMMAND", but if you are using PHP anyway you can run a query to get and then if statements in PHP to decide what to subtract from where

Comment: @oMi Shah It's a reduction. So the total stock is 150. I know why not total-purchased but there is more to it then this example. Thats why i need an array

Comment: @RiggsFolly youre right. I didn't explain is well enough. There is much bigger code behind it. Thats why I cant use multiple SQL commands.

Comment: Of course you can! So if you are baffled by the existing code, maybe the next question should start by showing us that code

Comment: I understand you want to fill the order ("purchased") with what is available in stock at different stacks. In every loop, get the difference. When it's negative, subtract the rest from the next stack. as soon as your order is filled, break the loop. If it's not filled at end of loop, you might want to reject the order and leave the stock untouched. therefore, you might want to check the total available stock first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achive that with a simple foreach loop.

```
$purchased = 45;
$stock     = [40, 50, 60];

$newStock = function ($purchased, $stock) {
    foreach ($stock as &$item) {
        $delta     = $item - $purchased;
        $item      = $delta > 0 ? $delta : 0;
        $purchased = $delta < 0 ? abs($delta) : 0;
    }
    return $stock;
};

print_r($newStock($purchased, $stock));
```

#### Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 45
    [2] => 60
)
```

Comment: @DataConnect I've even simplified my answer. The original stock still keeps untouched.